# Angular app, how to add html & css in the app component?

Tags: html, css, angular

[VScode error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anzml.png)I generated a new component(bmi calc) in my angular app, then downloaded a html/css template of bmi calculator functionality and pasted the html and css content of the template into the bmicalc.component.html & bmicalc.component.css file in my app, but the app is not running?

This is my error(the image of my error)

Comment: can you please provide your component code  and template code?

Comment: Its better to provide a plnkr for such kind of questions

Comment: You need to post your code, or post a plnkr link.. no one can help you without it

Comment: can i post a github link?

Comment: @AnuradhaGunasekara  (https://github.com/praharshb/bmi-sof/blob/master/bmicalc.html) this is the html code

Comment: @AnuradhaGunasekara  (https://github.com/praharshb/bmi-sof/tree/master/bmicalc)  this is the bmicalc component part of my angular app

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers

Comment: @praharshb - Added answer , But please make sure you ask questions correctly with some code snippet when you are asking question like "code isn't working".  SO not a place where problems solved automatically without knowing any hint of problem. or no one is  magician here :)

Comment: @raVan96 I think I am having an error in typescript.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/anzml.png) The image link is the screenie of my error.Can u please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As code given in your github files , below is working piece of code. I just updated your code.

You can check the updated code here on StackBlitz([Working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bmi-calculator)) -

You can check demo [here](https://angular-bmi-calculator.stackblitz.io)

> Note : =I have just updated your code to make it work only as you got
>   those `Uncaught error of compute function`. Not sure about correct
>   calculation so you need to look on that part.

Just few suggestions

1. Add code snippet when you ask this type of question
2. Use appropriate names to variable, Avoid use `i, ii, fv, kv` type of variables.
3. `.ts` file is there to write presentation logic whatever you want to apply on the form.
4. Your code should be well-formatted. Clean html.
5. Avoid using inline css, Use `.css` file for it.

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working now.Thanks for your suggestions, I will change the way I ask questions.

Comment: This link image is the error after using your code. (https://github.com/praharshb/bmi-sof/blob/master/bmicalc/bmiproblem2.PNG) can u help?

Comment: @praharshb Sorry I didn't realise You have updated question, I have also updated stackblitz code please check once again. Don't forget to accept this answer if it works correctly at your end :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your updated answer. Now its working properly, I'm sorry I have accepted now.(Apologize)

Comment: its my pleasure, and glad that your problem solved. by the way you need to understand those changes why we have did those changes In code. Please don't just follow that code blindly. You can post this type of question will try to explain that in answer.

Comment: Ya can u please explain that? I believe that was an error with the datatype, did we have typecast?